# When adding custom Document Sets to sharepoint shared documents programmatically, how do I assign one of the custom field value?

Tags: sharepoint, document-set

```
Hashtable docProps = new Hashtable();

      docProps.Add("Field1", myvalue);
      docProps.Add("Field2", "slsl");
      docProps.Add("Field3", "wwowowo");

try

{

     DocumentSet ds = DocumentSet.Create(list.RootFolder, "mydocumentset", list.ContentTypes["CustomDocumentSet"].Id, docProps);

}
```

This will add the document set, but value of the hashtalbe is not being accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and this is how I solved it. Basically we are referring to a wrong name. You can find teh correct property name by looping through the fieldlinks in the contentType.
DocumentSet docSet = DocumentSet.Create(parentFolder, DocumentSetName, docsetCT.Id, properties,true);

put a quick watch on below and see teh property names by looping through the fieldlinks.

```
docSet.ContentType.FieldLinks[0]
```

I hope it solves your problem.
I spent quite some time on this.

Regards
Abir

Answer (score 0):

you are missing some input parameters for the create method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee588760.aspx